# Removing all Javascript events from a page and putting them back

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events, unbind

I'd like to "pause" all the events of a page which means removes all the event set... and be able to put them back after.

Even the first part = removing all the events of a page, I don't see how to do so! Do you have ideas?

I don't find anything working for it!

Edit:

Why? I want to act in a page already loaded. The user will interact with the page and I want to control the interaction... so remove all the interactions previously set.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There's probably a much better solution.

Comment: If you want to prevent the users from triggering any events, you could put a <div> element over the page that acts a invisible cloak... You could remove this when you want to unpause....

Comment: The div will not prevent key events, tabbing around to links in the background

Comment: The div hack was a way I tried but I need the user to be able to select text... and of course he won't with a div above all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the currently solution I use: **it doesn't solve the problem totally!**

I stop the event during the capture phase: I put a listener on the document object to listen to all events in the capture phase and stop propagation.

+:

- List item
- Solves partially the problem

-:

- doesn't work for IE (no capture phase)
- if there are others events attached to the document, there are fired before my listener.

Do you have a better solution?

P.S.: I'll continue to update this post if I find a better solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unbind()` to remove all events

```
$.unbind();
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Add some jQuery and things get much simpler.

Comment: There is no static method to unbind all events, `$.unbind()` would throw an error.  This works on an element, not statically on `jQuery` itself.

Comment: Also, doesn't unbind only remove elements added with jquery.bind?

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work for me. I'm acting into the page after it has been loaded. I added information in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to store all the event listeners in a eventMap.

```
EventMap = {

    listeners:[],
    paused:false,

    mapListener:function(eventDispacter, eventType, eventHandler) {
        listeners.push({eD:eventDispacter, eT:eventType, eH:eventHandler});

        if(!paused)
            eventDispacter.addEventListener(eventType, eventHandler);
    },

    unMapListener:function(eventDispacter, eventType, eventHandler) {
        for( var i=0; i<listeners.length; i++) {
            var listener = listeners[i];

            if(listener.eD == eventDispacter && listener.eT == eventType && listener.eH == eventHandler) {
                listeners.splice(listeners.indexOf(listener), 1);
                eventDispacter.removeEventListener(eventType, eventHandler);
            }               
        }
    },

    pauseEvents:function() {
        if(!paused) {}
            for( var i=0; i<listeners.length; i++) {
                var listener = listeners[i];
                listener.eD.removeEventHandler(listener.eT, listener.eH);
            }
        }
    },

    unPauseEvents:function() {
        if(paused) {}
            for( var i=0; i<listeners.length; i++) {
                var listener = listeners[i];
                listener.eD.addEventHandler(listener.eT, listener.eH);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Add events with**

```
<script>
    function handleClick( e ) {
        alert('Button Clicked');
    }

    EventMap.mapListener(document.getElementById('myButton'), 'click', handleClick);
</script>
```

**Pause Events with**

```
EventMap.pauseEvents();
```

Comment: This is similar code to the AS3 RobotLegs methods, which are awesome!

Comment: Same than previous, this code is usefull but not in my case :( the events are already there.

Answer (score 0):

for any AJAX interactions you can certainly at least abort any connections using [ajax queue](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajaxqueue) and for any current animations, you can use [stop();](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of detaching all event handlers, you can have a global boolean variable `paused` which would be checked in all event handlers.

```
var paused = false;

function handle_some_click(e) {
    if (!paused) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said, I act in a page already loaded, I don't have access to all the eventListener... Thanks for this proposition.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you would do this... but you could put all of your javascript into an external .js file (as you should already.  Then have a single javascript function that's hardcoded into your page... it would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="toggle" src="/myExternalJS.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
var hidden = false;

function toggleScripts() {
     if(hidden) {
          document.getElementById('toggle').setAttribute('src' '/none.js');
    } else {
          document.getElementById('toggle').setAttribute('src' '/myExternalJS.js');
    }
}
```

I think this would work...
}

Comment: You think wrong... changing the source doesn't "un-execute" the javascript or remove the event handlers added